# SFML parse error with qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, sfml

I'm trying to set up SFML with qt creator, this is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += F:/SFML-1.6/include
  LIBS += "F:/SFML-1.6/lib/libsfml-graphics-s-d.a"
          "F:/SFML-1.6/lib/libsfml-window-d.a"
          "F:/SFML-1.6/lib/libsfml-system-s-d.a"
}
```

And I'm trying to run the following code, which is tested and runs without errors or warnings on codeblocks:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

Window myWin(VideoMode(860, 600, 32), "Hello sfml!");
const Input& in1 = myWin.GetInput();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    while(myWin.IsOpened()) {
        Event event1;
        while(myWin.GetEvent(event1)) {
            if(in1.IsKeyDown(Key::J)) {
                myWin.Close();
            }
        }
        myWin.Display();
    }
}
```

However I'm getting

```
c:\Documents and Settings\Stefan.MONA-H6H4KPUJNF\Desktop\C++\SfmlLearning\SfmlLearning.pro:9: error: Parse Error ('"F:/SFML-1.6/lib/libsfml-window-d.a"')
```

I understand what it means but it makes no sense, I have the file in that exact directory, I double-checked. Here's the directory where the libs are installed:

[image]

Comment: I dont know but I've never used `LIBS +=` with a `.a` file

Comment: Yeah I fixed it to LIBS += -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio however now I'm getting cannot open <SFML/System.hpp> no such file or directory :(

Comment: Is the path to SFML directory in the include path?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add line continuation marks at the end of lines 8 and 9 of your .pro-file. Qmake does expect all the statements to be in one line:-(